# Is there a git hook after changing tracked files on disk

Tags: git

I know git has several hooks, but I can't find one **after changing tracked files on disk**. For example `clone`, `checkout`, `reset --hard` may change tracked files on disk. Are there some hooks can include this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hook called after `reset` but there is the [`post-checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L165) hook that is called after doing a checkout (or a `clone`, except when inhibited by `--no-checkout`).

A very basic hook would be

```sh
#! /bin/bash

PREVIOUS_HEAD_SHA="$1"    # null if run after a clone
NEW_HEAD_SHA="$2"         # may be identical to the PREVIOUS_HEAD_SHA
BRANCH_CHECKOUT="$3"      # set to 1 if it was a branch checkout

# put your code here
```